# How do I know if the canister of silica gel or strips of vapor corrosion inhibitor have lose its effectiveness in absorb moisture?

Tags: tools, rust-removal

Usually I put canister of silica gel or strips of vapor corrosion inhibitor in my cupboard (that contains many metal repair tools) to absorb moisture so that I keep the rust at bay.

So, How do I know if the canister of silica gel or strips of vapor corrosion inhibitor have lose its effectiveness in absorb moisture? (so that I can replace them with new ones. or do they really last a lifetime?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silica Gel often has a color indicator, either going from blue(dry) to pink(wet), or from orange(dry) to green(wet). By heating the gel to 250 °F for 2 hours, you can restore the gel to its dry state and reuse it.

Comment: Make sure it's in an appropriate container before you put it in the oven - ie: not in plastic or paper

Comment: Never thought that I can heat the gel at 121 °C (or 250 °F) to restore the gel. Good.

Comment: Also, by the way, I have a Gel of white color. Is it dry or wet? Also, I have another Gel of cyan color, can I consider it as blue color?

Comment: Also, is it possible to heat the strips of vapor corrosion inhibitor like the way we heat the gel to restore it to its dry state?

Comment: @Jack The color is from an added chemical. I think the Gel defaults to white and doesn't change by itself, so the white may be some Gel without a color indicator. I don't think there's any harm in restoring it prematurely if you're not sure. No idea on the vapor strips.